# Lenovo P50 is not booting from NVMe SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, clone, nvme

I bought Lenovo P50 recently with regular HDD and decided to have NVMe now. I put the NVMe without pulling the HDD out. I used the EaseUS Todo to clone the Windows to NVMe drive. It copied successfully. Then I pulled out the HDD, but the laptop will not boot from the NVMe drive. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you clone just the Windows *partition*, or the whole Windows *drive*? Also, did you clone any other partitions that are on the same HDD?

Here's a very brief breakdown of what has to be done to successfully clone Windows (other than copying the Windows system partition), depending on the way it was installed:

- Installed in UEFI mode: Clone the [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) (ESP) exactly, making sure to get the filesystem type flag, etc. exactly mirrored to the new drive
- Installed in BIOS mode: Clone the [Boot Sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector) exactly, byte for byte

If you did one of those things and it still won't boot, you should go back and boot Windows on the HDD side and verify that you can "mount" (via Disk Management) the NVMe drive and make sure it works for reading and writing files off of the copied Windows system partition. If that doesn't work, it's probably hardware issue, or the copy of the Windows partition failed and you should try it again (likely filesystem damage from an incomplete copy).